# Is there a characterization of smooth $G$-equivariant functions $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, representation-theory, topological-vector-spaces

If $G$ is a compact Lie group acting smoothly on $\mathbb R^n$ by orthogonal matrices, a result of G. Schwartz characteriezs the smooth $G$-invariant functions $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ as smooth functions of the $G$-invariant *polynomials* $P(\mathbb R^n)^G$. (See [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/65264/integral-representation-of-higher-order-derivatives) for a discussion.)

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3124905/which-smoothness-properties-are-preserved-under-ramified-covering-maps/3124946#3124946) I wondered whether a Riemannian metric descends smoothly through a ramified covering map, which led to a similar problem:

> **Question.** When $G$ is a finite group (more generally, a compact Lie group) with smooth orthogonal actions on $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$, what is known about $G$-equivariant smooth maps $$f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m ?$$

(Schwartz' theorem is the case $m = 1$.)